# getResourceAsStream.readAllBytes() reads more bytes than the source file actually has

Tags: java, file, jar, io

I'm writing a utility method that loads files from a .jar file into ByteBuffer. For some reason it's returning more bytes than exist in the source file.

Relevant code ([Full class](https://github.com/harding-capstone/engine/blob/af42c738470393197325f1d06c8b5d563f6eca77/src/main/java/com/shepherdjerred/capstone/engine/engine/resource/ByteBufferLoader.java)):

```
try (var stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath)) {
  var bytes = stream.readAllBytes();

  log.info(bytes.length + " bytes or " + bytes.length / 1024 + "kb");
}
```

When testing my method, I pass in a file path, "/fonts/m5x7.ttf". According to the macOS finder, the size of this file is 34,300 bytes (33kb) or 37 KB on disk. When testing my method, the following is printed: 39090 bytes or 38kb. Testing was done on macOS, compiled using Java 11.

For some reason I'm getting 5KB more than the file actually has.

EDIT: Strangely, I'm able to load a .png file just fine. I tried loading another .ttf file and it has the same issue.

My method outputs: 356958 bytes or 348kb. The actual file size: 356,958 bytes (393 KB on disk)

Comment: Is m5x7.ttf just a test file?  Because normally, you don’t read a font into a ByteBuffer, you pass the InputStream to a font loading method.

Comment: It's intended for actual use in my program. I'm using lwjgl which wraps native libraries. The library I'm using requires the font data passed as a ByteBuffer. You can see it in use here: (https://github.com/harding-capstone/engine/blob/dd959ff642724f9a4e6033f7ca4ece4af3b64ef7/src/main/java/com/shepherdjerred/capstone/engine/engine/graphics/font/FontLoader.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was an issue with maven.

[Java class.getResourceAsStream() returns incorrect byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670071/java-class-getresourceasstream-returns-incorrect-byte)

Once I disabled resource filtering, the issue no longer appeared.