# Error at compiling Jenkins build for Maven Project: Error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8

Tags: maven, jenkins

Below is my pom.xml image. I found some answer and tried all the possible ways but getting same error in jenkins console output

Tried are ways which I tried
1.  [How to configure encoding in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017695/how-to-configure-encoding-in-maven)
2. [Error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8 during maven compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978013/error-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf8-during-maven-compilation)

tried adding properties too but so change in result

Compilation Error in jenkin is:
[Compilation Error in Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxgOW.jpg)

[pom.xml image**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI54U.jpg)

Please review and help with appropriate answer

Comment: please do not paste external image links! if it dissapear grom hosting, this post will unusable to other community members!

Comment: sure will take care