# Jenkins Maven encoding and languages

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, character-encoding, appium

I have issue with JENKINS and MAVEN regarding encoding.
I am doing tests and one of the tests is changing language to domestic language (Romanian)

If I use UTF-8 in pom.xml I get "unmappable character" error when compiling, I have changed encoding to "cp1252", this encoding doesn't give me that error but it also doesn't find the elements that are using domestic language, I get ROM?‚NÄ‚ instead of ROMÂNĂ.

Is there any way to resolve this issue with multiple encoding?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979120/4175515) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8 during maven compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978013/error-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf8-during-maven-compilation)

Comment: You need to find out which codepage was used to save your source files, or convert them to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

The unmappable character error indicates a mismatch between Character encodings of input files and the Maven tooling.

Did you set the encoding using this property? This ensures that all plugins will use UTF-8.

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
...
```

Also ensure that your source files are actually UTF-8. For more tips, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979120/8092868

Comment: the problem I get when using UTF-8 is some characters are causing maven to give "unmappable character" error when compiling

Comment: If you tell Maven to use UTF-8, then your input files must also be UTF-8. You can verify the character encoding in e.g. Notepad++ in the bottom right of the status bar.